# Consumir dados JSON vindo do bando Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Eu criei em meu `MYSQL` 3 campos `ID`, `Cliente`, `Produtos` onde são cadastrados via `JSON` as informações do `Cliente` e os `produtos` que ele selecionou.

JSON Cliente

```
{
     "nomecliente":"Cristiano",
     "email":"cristiano_3b@yahoo.com.br",
     "telefone":"16991337891",
     "mensagem":"rerwerewrwerewr" 
}
```

JSON Produto

```
[
  {
     "nome":"Samsung ali",
     "quantidade":1
  },{
     "nome":"notebook hp",
     "quantidade":1
  }
]
```

Como posso exibir este retorno em `PHP`?

Comment: Como você recupera essas informações no banco, teoricamente `json_decode` resolve

Answer (score 1):

é so usar o `json_decode();`

```
$retorno = json_decode($o_seu_Json);

$retornoAssociativo = json_decode($o_seu_Json,true); //a boolean true no parametro transforma a array em uma array associativa
```

Mas certifica-te que a o valor esta codificado em UTF-8, senao tens que passar a constante `JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE` mas so se o teu `PHP` for superior à versão 7.2

Mais informações aqui [Documentação json_decode();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, mas não rolou, por favor pode dar uma olhada? while($msgn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){  $retorno = json_decode($msgn['cliente']);   }  echo  $retornoAssociativo = json_decode($msgn,true);

Comment: onde $msgn['cliente'] é o campo onde tem os dados do cliente

Comment: ok olhe seu codigo esta errado por alguns motivos ao fazer o while dessa forma a sua variavel $retorno vai ser subscrita sempre dessa forma ou seja por cada ciclo o seu $retorno nao sera igual a = 1,2,3,4,5,6 mas simplesmente = a 6

Comment: faça isto no seu codigo pra entender o que esta acontecendo `while($msgn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ var_dump(json_decode($msgn['cliente'])); }`

Comment: object(stdClass)#4 (4) { ["nomecliente"]=> string(9) "Cristiano" ["email"]=> string(25) "cristiano_3b@yahoo.com.br" ["telefone"]=> string(11) "16991337891" ["mensagem"]=> string(15) "rerwerewrwerewr" } object(stdClass)#4 (4) { ["nomecliente"]=> string(9) "Cristiano" ["email"]=> string(25) "cristiano_3b@yahoo.com.br" ["telefone"]=> string(11) "16991337891" ["mensagem"]=> string(14) "mensagem teste" }

Comment: `while($msgn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ $retorno[] =json_decode($msgn['cliente'])); }print_r($retorno);` vai lhe imprimir todos os elementos da array criada agora ou seja dentro do loop o `$retorno[]` vai adicionar sempre um novo objeto a cada iteração

Comment: pra aceder à primeira pessoa $retorno[0], se quiseres o nome da primeira pessoa $retorno[0]["nomecliente"] etc

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\carrinho\painel\recebidos.php:78 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\carrinho\painel\recebidos.php on line 78 
------------------- meu código ----------------- echo $retorno[0]["nomecliente"];

Comment: foi porque nao usaste o segundo parametro como indiquei em cima

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100014/discussion-between-scrapbench-and-cristiano-facirolli).

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli indique que a resposta foi aceite pff ou vou continuar recebendo notificações ahah

Answer (score 0):

```
// string json vai receber os dados do cliente no formato json

 $json_str = '{
    "nomecliente":"Cristiano",
    "email":"cristiano_3b@yahoo.com.br",
    "telefone":"16991337891",
    "mensagem":"rerwerewrwerewr" 
  }';

// faz o parsing na string e gera um obj php
$obj = json_decode($json_str);
//imprime o conteúdo do objeto 
echo "Nome: $obj->nomecliente<br>";
echo "Email: $obj->email<br>";
echo "Tel: $obj->telefone<br>";
echo "Msg: $obj->mensagem<br>";
```

No caso do json Produto que contém mais de um registro, você teria que representar esse múltiplo objeto json usando um array, exemplo:

```
 // Você tem esse json com 2 elementos:

 {
    produtos: [
        {"nome":"Samsung ali", "quantidade": 1},
        {"nome":"notebook hp", "quantidade": 1}
    ]
 };

 // string json "um array com 2 elementos" ficaria assim

 $json_str = '{"produtos": '. '[
    {"nome":"Samsung ali", "quantidade": '. 1 .'},'.
    '{"nome":"notebook hp", "quantidade": '. 1 .'}'.                
']}';

// faz o parsing da string, criando o array "produtos"
$jsonObj = json_decode($json_str);
$produtos = $jsonObj->produtos;

// agora é só percorrer o array, imprimindo cada produto
foreach ( $produtos as $product ) {
    echo "Nome: $product->nome <br> Quantidade: $product->quantidade<br>"; 
  }
```

**RESOLUÇÃO**

```
    $lista = "SELECT * FROM contato ORDER BY data_msg DESC";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $lista) or die(mysqli_error());

    // tenha certeza q esta vindo obj php e n json e tente:
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
       $retorno[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $result);
    }
    echo json_encode($retorno);
   // com essa linha acima você tem um obj json
```

Caso contrário json_decode resolve.

Comment: Obrigadp pela resposta mas seria algo assim? $lista = "SELECT * FROM contato ORDER BY data_msg DESC"; $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $lista) or die(mysqli_error()); $q = array(); while ($td = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {$q[] = $td['cliente'];} $dados = json_encode($q);echo "Nome: $dados->nomecliente<br>";

Comment: estou tendo o seguinte retorno string(117) "{"nomecliente":"Cristiano","email":"cristiano_3b@yahoo.com.br","telefone":"16991337891","mensagem":"rerwerewrwerewr"}"

Comment: se eu tentar assim while ($td = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                                            $q[] = $td['cliente'];
                                        }
                                        var_dump(json_decode($q));
ele me retorna com erro Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\carrinho\painel\recebidos.php on line 78
NULL

Comment: a msg diz q deve vir uma string de $q quando você faz json_decode($q), por ser uma matriz associativa q tem varios campos, entao tenta:

while ($td = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $dados = $td['cliente'];
}

$json = json_decode($dados);
foreach($json as $item){
    foreach($item as $i){
        echo $i;
    }
}

Comment: me retorna Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\carrinho\painel\recebidos.php on line 77